# JSON error: Trying to get information from JSON result

Tags: json

I'm trying to create a small php file that gets info from URL (url responds JSON) and get a information from Data, but everytime I try to do that I get error: Notice: Trying to get property 'Data' of non-object in
This is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("allow_url_fopen", 1);
if(isset($_GET['email'])) {
    $email = $_GET['email'];
    $url = "https://api.weleakinfo.com/v2/public/email/$email");
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$obj = json_decode($result);    
echo $obj->Data;


} else {
    echo "Not valid email";
}
?>
```

The link its working perfectly and returning the Data but when I try using it with php its not working.. Is it possible because its not set into the headers GET request or something ?

Comment: shouldnt it be `json_encode`? decode will surely write it as a string instead of a json object with readable properties?

Comment: `json_decode` is definitely the correct function to convert JSON string into an object: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: `$result` is actually an HTML website containing this error message: "This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data."

Comment: @FelixEdelmann how can I make a correct GET request then ?

Comment: The problem is that the server think's that you're a (malicious) bot. Probably, you have to add additional header info. You can use Firefox's or Chrome's developer tools to discover which headers are sent using the browser, and then use the exact same in your script. If that works, simply try which headers aren't needed and can be omitted.

Comment: How can I do that ?